# Hashmap arraylist (java)

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

Okay, so I'm fairly new to programming so apologies if this problem is really simple, I've created an `ArrayList` inside my `Hash Map` so that I can add more than one value into my hash map.

My code looks fine (to me) but theres an error on this line "mymap.add(module, new ArrayList>());" saying ( or [ expected.

Wasted way too much time trying to figure this out so thought I'd post here. Thanks in advance for any help. Also: yes I need to do it this way and no I can't use `guava MultiMap`.

```
public class hashArray {
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> mymap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();
public hashArray() {}
public void addEntryHR( String module, Integer result ) {
mymap.add(module, new ArrayList<Integer>>());
```

Comment: put is not adding my entries into the arraylist?

Answer (score 4):

There is a typo **and** a bug in your line:

```
//         The typo is right here    v
mymap.add(mod, new ArrayList<Integer>>());
```

Remove one of the `>` and change `add` to `put`:

```
mymap.put(mod, new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

The error you get, is about the typo. Fixing that typo will give you an error about `add` to be an unknown method.

Answer (score 2):

#### The problems

- You create a new `ArrayList` in `new ArrayList<Integer>>()` (with contains a syntax error as well - a `>` too many), but never add `number` to it.
- You are calling `add` on a `HashMap`, which doesn't have this method. For maps, it is called `put`.

#### Proposed solution

Please see the code below

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> myMap = new HashMap<>();

public void addEntryHR(String mod, Integer number) {
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    numbers.add(number);

    myMap.put(mod, numbers);
}
```

#### Other remarks

**Use interfaces**
It is advised to use the interfaces of the collections rather than the implementations. This means `Map<String, String> myMap` instead of `HashMap<String, String> myMap` and `List<Integer>` instead of `ArrayList<Integer>`.
Why do this? Because this allows you to be flexible in the collections you use and reduce maintenance effort. Say you change your mind and want to use `LinkedList` instead of `ArrayList`, then you just have to change one `new ArrayList<>()` to `new LinkedList<>()` instead of all the `ArrayList` variables used throughout the code.

Comment: Thank you I believe this is the solution I was looking for, however one problem, when I change my code to this I get the following error: "diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6 (use-source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)" - so I edited the project properties to be using source 7 and 90% of my code now appears non-responsive. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Is it linked with the right version of JDK? What IDE are you using? I can't help much without any proper details. If the problem still persists, I suggest raising a new question on how to use Java 7+ with your IDE. As a workaround, you can use `new ArrayList<Integer>()` and `new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>()` until you resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to first get the list out from map object like below-

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = mymap.get(mod);

if (list==null){
    //then create new ArrayList object and assign to list
    list=new ArrayList<Integer>();
 }
  list.add(number);  //adding new number to the list
  mymap.put(mod,list); //storing in map
```